# What to do with scratched top tube on carbon fiber frame with no structural damage?

Tags: repair, carbon, damage

[image: scratched frame]

No physical damage, if i press into it nor while riding.

I did wipe the surface to get rid of dirt and paint chip. Attached also a video to demonstrate the scratch. Should i put epoxy or tape or nail polish on it?

[Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdGcRSn1iz8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any cracking, and its hard to tell from the photo/video, but it also doesn't seem that deep, so that rules out the need for epoxy for either bonding or to act as a filler.

I'd start with nail polish - i've had fairly good results with it although not on such a large area.

Tape as a last resort as its ugly.

Comment: ok i did the nail polish and seems to work, 3 layers then sanding it in fine grit, and then put black electric tape and seems fine